# Show Var from Highchart to Dialog Box

Tags: codeigniter, variables

i have improve my code using highchart. I'm using plotoption to echo variabel just like in http://jsfiddle.net/gF8Cf/3/ .

Here is my highchart code :

```
plotOptions: {
               series: 
               {
                 cursor: 'pointer',
                 point: {
                   events: {
                    click: function box() {
                    var week = this.category;
                    $("#dialog").dialog({
                        title: "Detail Data",
                        buttons: {
                            Close: function () {
                               $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }
                    });
             },
```

And for the next, i set the dialog box by :

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
<div style="margin-left: 35px; font-size:12px;">
IT IS WEEK :
<?php 
   box();
   echo $week
?>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to show data this.category when the dialog-pop-up-box opened.

The problem is, did i set the wrong code for $week ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
var week = '<?php $week ?>';
});
```

Try to load the week variable on window load.

Comment: And how to get var on windows load ?